# NSIS - How to separate Sections?

Tags: nsis

I want to separate the Section of the files to be extracted by the installer and the files to be deleted by the uninstaller while both Section has the same Section name.

**CODE**:

```
#Initialize variable
!define APPLICATION_NAME "Demo"

#Installer section
Section "${APPLICATION_NAME}"
 SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
 WriteUninstaller "$INSTDIR\Uninstaller.exe"
SectionEnd

#Uninstaller section
Section "${APPLICATION_NAME}"
 Delete "$INSTDIR\Uninstaller.exe"
 RMDir "$INSTDIR"
SectionEnd
```

**IMAGE**:

[image]

Comment: Please post your code directly to SO. If it is too much code, please reduce it to a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry. I have now edited my post.

Comment: thanks for editing your post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Uninstaller section names are prefixed with 'un.'

```
Section "Demo"
SectionEnd

Section "un.Demo"
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the answer to my question.